# Binary returns permission denied even with 777 rights

Tags: permissions, binary

```
[adela@zen ~]$ dir-open /
bash: /home/adela/.toolbox/bin/dir-open: Permission denied
```

The weird thing is, that both directory and binaries has 777 permisions, and binaries cannot be executed - permission denied.

There is a ~/.toolbox/bin directory, ls -la:

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 adela adela 4,0K 14. zář 18.34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 adela adela 4,0K  5. zář 19.38 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  302 22. čen 16.13 checksum*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela 1,3K 18. čec 17.21 dir-open*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  937  4. zář 21.05 nas-open*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  300  1. úno  2021 po-to-xls*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  565  8. zář 16.18 run*
drwxrwxrwx  2 adela adela 4,0K  5. zář 19.03 .stfolder/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela 1,8K  1. úno  2021 subtitles-renamer*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  104 31. říj  2021 terminal*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 adela adela  300  1. úno  2021 xls-to-po*
```

bin directory is also present in $PATH:

```
/home/adela/.toolbox/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

The contents of one of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script makes file manager open just right.
# called from ~/.toolbox/bin/dir-open

APP="pcmanfm"
DESKTOP=$(wmctrl -d | grep \* | awk '{print $1}') # number of active desktop
APPSINDESKTOP=$(wmctrl -l -x | awk -v var="$DESKTOP" '($2 == var)' | grep -ic "$APP") # windows in active desktop
WIN=$(wmctrl -l -x | awk -v var="$DESKTOP" '($2 == var)' | grep -i "$APP" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n "1p")
window=$(printf "%d\n" $WIN)


if [[ $APPSINDESKTOP -ge 1 ]]; then
  ACTIVE=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
  if [[ $ACTIVE = $window ]]; then
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        xdotool windowminimize $window # Minimize
      else
        $APP "$1" # New tab
    fi
  else
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      wmctrl -ia $WIN # Focus window
    else
      $APP "$1" # New tab
      wmctrl -ia $WIN # Focus window
    fi
  fi
else
  echo "no app on active desktop"
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      $APP "/mnt/DATA" -n & # add -n for pcmanfm
    else
      $APP "$1" -n & # add -n for pcmanfm
  fi
  sleep 0.3
  WIN=$(wmctrl -l -x | awk -v var="$DESKTOP" '($2 == var)' | grep -i "$APP" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n "1p")
  wmctrl -i -R $WIN -e 0,$POSX,$POSY,$WIDTH,$HEIGHT # Resize existing window
  # wmctrl -ia $WIN # Focus window
fi

echo -e "Debug info: \n\nDesktop: $DESKTOP \nWindow: $WIN \nAppsInDesktop: $APPSINDESKTOP\n"

exit 0
```

- None of the binaries can be run.
- Same result when run with sudo.
- Arco Linux
- Directory is also shared with another computer (Arch), where binaries are used with no problem.

Any idea what might be potentially wrong?

Comment: What is inside this tool: `dir-open`? Looks like shell script.

Comment: Is something mounted with `noexec`?

Comment: Yes, those files are bash or python scripts.

noexec - no, I'm not aware of that.

Comment: Can you execute other scripts or binaries located in or under your home directory?

Comment: Does `bash ~/.toolbox/bin/dir-open /` give errors? Maybe try adding `-x` to the command to trace execution.

Comment: @AndyDalton You were right, finally I found out: 
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /home/adela type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user)

However, I'm able to run bash a script in home folder normal way (via shell).

Comment: @doneal24 It works this way, no errors.

Comment: When you say you are able to run `bash` scripts, I'm assuming you run them by saying `bash some-script` and not `./some-script`, right?  The former would not try to _execute_ the script, only pass its name to `bash` (which would read it, which is allowed, and run the commands in it, which is also allowed).

Comment: @Kusalananda Typically I run scripts via my run binary, which decides which interpreter to use (bash / python). I used to run scripts with `bash some-script` before, though. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

worth mentioning is **selinux**, any time I have a problem that I do not quickly understand or scratch my head on I do a `setenforce 0` to temporarily put selinux into permissive mode to see if that's what is causing the problem.

but **permission denied on executing a binary** what comes to mind is **noexec** as the mount option.  Although I am not sure if that results in a *permission denied* message or if it results in just nothing ever happening.  type `mount` and see if the mount option of *noexec* is present for where the binary is located.  And then copy the binary from that mounted device to some other folder location which does not have the noexec mount option and see if the binary works.

Comment: You're were right, I found this: 
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /home/adela type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user)

However, I'm able to run bash script in shell, e.g. `bash script.sh` with no problems.

Comment: My /etc/fstab file did not state neither noexec or exec, so I added exec, and it works now! Thank you! I've learned something today.